# Can I combine the Blink Spell and a readied action to move around in the ethereal plane?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, readied-action, ethereal-plane

Assuming I have cast the [Blink](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/blink) spell on the previous turn and that I roll over 11 on the D20 for Blink at the end of my turn, can readying an action with the trigger "When I enter the ethereal plane, I run forward" during my turn allow me to move around for the time I remain in the ethereal plane?

If so, what rules, if any, govern my movement for the time I am on the ethereal plane? For instance can I walk through solid objects like walls?

If not, is it an issue with the wording of the trigger, or is there something restricting me from using my movement?

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/124103/23196, https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/75966/23196

Comment: Removed references to the "Dash" action as it wasn't really relevant to my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Yes, you'll be free to move but must return to within 10 feet of where you entered

From the description of the Ready action in the PHB or the [Basic Rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#Ready):

> First, you decide what perceivable circumstance
> will trigger your reaction. Then, you choose the action
> you will take in response to that trigger, or you choose
> to move up to your speed in response to it.

Moving to the Ethereal Plane is certainly perceivable, so it works as a trigger. As per [this QA](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/74423/23196), there is nothing about being in the ethereal plane that prevents you from taking a reaction.

As for limitations on movement, the DMG has this to offer on the Ethereal Plane:

> A traveler on the Ethereal Plane is invisible and
> utterly silent to someone on the overlapped plane, and
> solid objects on the overlapped plane don't hamper
> the movement of a creature in the Border Ethereal.
> The exceptions are certain magical effects (including
> anything made of magical force) and living beings. This
> makes the Ethereal Plane ideal for reconnaissance,
> spying on opponents, and moving around without being
> detected. The Ethereal Plane also disobeys the laws
> of gravity; a creature there can move up and down as
> easily as walking.

So you can move up to your speed, you can move through any solid objects, and you can even fly, but you can't move through other creatures (or force effects). Unfortunately, *Blink* stipulates:

> At the start of you next turn, and when the spell ends if you are on the Ethereal Plane, you return to an unoccupied space of your choice that you can see **within 10 feet of the space you vanished from**.

So you can spy through walls with *Blink*, but you can't travel with it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To best answer my question could you tell me what you would say about moving through walls and other objects? Let me know if you think this should be its own question.

Comment: @YannickMG Does the new version work?

Comment: It's perfect. Thank you. :) Do you think editing my question (and thus your answer) to remove any references to readying the "dash" action would make the Q&A better?

Comment: @YannickMG Given that it seems to be more about moving in general and not about the Dash action, sure

Comment: Alright I did it.

Comment: Why couldn't you travel? If you're right up against the wall, and the wall is only 1 square (5 feet), you could reappear two squares away from the origin and be on the other side of the wall.

Comment: @Jason_c_o Yes you can go to the other side of a thin wall, but you can't go your whole 30ft of distance. You can move a bit, but not travel long distances. I suppose that is just a matter of preference of description.

Answer (score 7):

## You can use *Blink* to move in the Ethereal Plane

...because neither *Blink* nor the Ethereal Plane have rules that forbid movement.

In particular, the *Dungeon Master's Guide* states:

> A traveler on the Ethereal Plane is invisible and utterly silent to someone on the overlapped plane, and solid objects on the overlapped plane don't hamper the movement of a creature in the Border Ethereal. The exceptions are certain magical effects (including anything made of magical force) and living beings. This makes the Ethereal Plane ideal for reconnaissance, spying on opponents, and moving around without being detected. The Ethereal Plane also disobeys the laws of gravity; a creature there can move up and down as easily as walking.

However, Blink also states:

> At the start of you next turn, and when the spell ends if you are on the Ethereal Plane, you return to an unoccupied space of your choice that you can see **within 10 feet of the space you vanished from**.

In other words, traveling through the Ethereal plane with Blink will not help you travel the Material plane, unless (as [Jason_c_o](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/9625/jason-c-o) explains in [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/124137/42865)) you are trying to bypass a 5' deep obstacle.

You can also use Blink to move through walls, get a brief look at what's beyond, and then blink back to your initial location on the material plane.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do not intend to move further than 10 feet in the material world. What I do want to know is can I cross solid objects such as walls while in the ethereal plane? This could be useful for scouting while undetected, and other "shenanigans".

Comment: @YannickMG then I recommend editing your question, or even better, creating an entirely new question.

Comment: I intend "If so, what rules, if any, govern my movement for the time I am on the ethereal plane?" to cover this. I'll expand it with that specific example.

Comment: @YannickMG what can I say? I must be blind

Comment: If the wall is only 5 feet thick you could technically reappear on the other side as that would be 2 squares (10 feet) from your casting point.